# Stupid question: does my rear derailleur have a hanger?

Tags: derailleur-rear

I don't see it. The place where it should be seems to be part of the frame. If not, why not?

[image]

Comment: The derailleur "hangs" below the axle/quick release.  The piece of frame that hangs the derailleur below the axle is called the "derailleur hanger".  On aluminum/carbon frames this is a detachable/replaceable piece, on steel frames (such as yours) it is part of the frame (as it can be bent back into place).

Comment: Just a note on the side: The bolt above the quick-release nut isn't properly tightened!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hanger is part of the frame in this case. This is a pretty common design, though many newer frames will have the hanger as a removable part of the frame that can be replaced if damaged. In the case of your bike, if there is damage, you have to (carefully) bend it back to shape.